# Format Address String

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, I need to know the best way to split a string containing an address into separated fields so that I can reformat them. It has to be able to deal with different input formats.

```
AddressIn:           AddressOut:
                     StreetNumber:     StreetName:
'25 Main Street'   | '25'              'Main Street'
'25 MainStreet'    | '25'              'MainStreet'
'Main Street 25'   | '25'              'Main Street'
'MainStreet 25'    | '25'              'MainStreet'
'25B Main Street'  | '25B'             'Main Street'
'25B MainStreet'   | '25B'             'MainStreet'
'Main Street 25B'  | '25B'             'Main Street'
'MainStreet 25B'   | '25B'             'MainStreet'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avoid using SQL at all and see if you can do this from your application code!

Comment: I think you will find it quite difficult to define the rules necessary to reliably identify specific components of an arbitrary address string. If you can't define the rules in plain English, it's going to be difficult to code in SQL :)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I'm pulling the data from a DB attached to a vendor application & it's only stored as a string.

Comment: the variations in the original request are the only formats that are input into the given field I need to select from.

Comment: I had this before, with data coming from a call center, from free text forms. I recommend PAF-ing the address, and store the consistent data in your local database. With millions of rows to postcode format, you won't get away with split string function calls which are executed for each row.

Comment: Side note: I see no reason to even attempt something like this. Adresses come in so many flavours that its practically useless to try and format them in any way. See https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want, but I agree with the comments above, using SQL for this kind of parsing is not ideal.

```
select
CASE 
    WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%',theAddress)=1 
    THEN substring(theaddress,1,charindex(' ',theaddress) ) 
    ELSE rtrim(substring(theAddress,patindex('%[0-9]%',theAddress),99) )
END as StreetNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%',theAddress)=1 
    THEN substring(theaddress,charindex(' ',theAddress)+1,99) 
    ELSE substring(theAddress,1,patindex('%[0-9]%',theAddress)-1)
END as StreetName
FROM <yourtable>
```

Caveats, as you can see from the comments.

- Performance will not be very good, particularly if your table is
  large.
- Other address formats than your examples probably will break
  the code

Comment: Using the first part of this approach (getting the number of the street) which is much clearer, you can get the name of the street in a robuster way simply by replacing the already stripped down street number in the current record with empty string thus giving you the name of the street in a more reliable way.Testing the method of obtaining the street number more extensively and perfecting it will eliminate the need of a second method of obtaining the street name.

Comment: I agree, but then you need to extract the street number, store it somewhere and use a replace in the subsequent street name part.  Doable, but would make the query much more complex.   The above is a simple solution that matches his known address formats.   Not perfect, but pretty simple to use

Comment: sorry but just check it for `Main 25B Street` the output is `incorrect`

Comment: Main 25B street is not in the ops example address formats...   The ops stated the variations in is original request are the only expected input formats

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

**Step_1:** (split the string and extract only the part which containing number for street_number)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitAddress_1] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX)     
) 
RETURNS @output_2 TABLE(street_number NVARCHAR(50),street_name NVARCHAR(100))
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1)
    SET @delimiter=' '
    DECLARE @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX))
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    DECLARE @CHKStr VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        SET @CHKStr=SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)
        IF @CHKStr LIKE '%[0-9]%'BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @output_2(street_number) VALUES(@CHKStr)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(@chksTR)
        END 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    UPDATE @output_2
    SET street_name=
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' ' + splitdata FROM @output FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))
    RETURN 
END
```

and use it like:

```
select * from dbo.splitAddress_1('25B Main Street')
```

**Output:** `'25B'             'Main Street'`

**step_2:** (the step_1 is main idea and most important, below function is just fro making the select easy - the function may be different and can be wrote in different way)

```
CREATE TABLE address_table (AddressIn  NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO address_table VALUES
    ('25 Main Street'),
    ('25 MainStreet'),
    ('Main Street 25'),
    ('MainStreet 25'),
    ('25B Main Street'),
    ('25B MainStreet'),
    ('Main Street 25B'),
    ('MainStreet 25B'),
    ('Main 25B Street')
```

then

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitAddress_2]()
RETURNS @output TABLE(street_number NVARCHAR(50),street_name NVARCHAR(100))
BEGIN 
 DECLARE @adr varchar(200)
 DECLARE cr CURSOR
    FOR SELECT AddressIn FROM address_table
OPEN cr
FETCH NEXT FROM cr into @adr;
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin
insert into @output(street_number,street_name)
select * from dbo.splitAddress_1(@adr)
FETCH NEXT FROM cr into @adr;
end
close cr
deallocate cr
 RETURN 
END
```

and finally this query: `select * from dbo.splitAddress_2()`

**result:**
[image]

> **NOTE:** it does not matter if number part be at the beginning , mid or end of address string for example  for addresses like
>   `'Main 25B Street'`  this solution will work well.

Comment: Always try to avoid while loops and cursors if possible, for this solution it is so your approach is even more inefficient.

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch I'm sure in this scenario a small loop is much better than using a huge number of `built-in functions` within `case` statements with multiple `when`s, anyway, thanks for your comment, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Sparky modified for robustness.

```
DECLARE @Addresses TABLE (Address  NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @Addresses VALUES
    ('25 Main Street'),
    ('25 MainStreet'),
    ('Main Street 25'),
    ('MainStreet 25'),
    ('25B Main Street'),
    ('25B MainStreet'),
    ('Main Street 25B'),
    ('MainStreet 25B')
select
CASE 
    WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%',Address)=1 
    THEN substring(Address,1,charindex(' ',Address) ) 
    ELSE rtrim(substring(Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address),99) )
END as StreetNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%',Address)=1 
    THEN REPLACE(Address,substring(Address,1,charindex(' ',Address) ),'')
    ELSE REPLACE(Address,rtrim(substring(Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address),99) ),'')
END as StreetName
FROM @Addresses
```

Supposedly this code should handle better more types of addressess.

This version is with the extra exception:

```
DECLARE @Addresses TABLE (Address  NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @Addresses VALUES
    ('25 Main Street'),
    ('25 MainStreet'),
    ('Main Street 25'),
    ('MainStreet 25'),
    ('25B Main Street'),
    ('25B MainStreet'),
    ('Main Street 25B'),
    ('MainStreet 25B'),
    ('Main 25B Street')
select
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address))-patindex('%[0-9]%',Address) > 0
    THEN substring(Address, patindex('%[0-9]%',Address), CHARINDEX(' ',Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address))-patindex('%[0-9]%',Address))
    WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%',Address)=1 
    THEN substring(Address,1,charindex(' ',Address) ) 
    ELSE rtrim(substring(Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address),99) )
END as StreetNumber,
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address))-patindex('%[0-9]%',Address) > 0
    THEN REPLACE(Address,substring(Address, patindex('%[0-9]%',Address), CHARINDEX(' ',Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address))-patindex('%[0-9]%',Address)),'')
    WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%',Address)=1 
    THEN REPLACE(Address,substring(Address,1,charindex(' ',Address) ),'')
    ELSE REPLACE(Address,rtrim(substring(Address,patindex('%[0-9]%',Address),99) ),'')
END as StreetName
FROM @Addresses
```

Comment: Definitely another approach.   Thanks

Comment: **WRONG** sorry but just check it for `Main 25B Street` the output is incorrect

Comment: First i never claimed that the code i modified handles all exceptions to say "WRONG" i said its MORE robust please read the sentences in English apart from the code.
Second this format type is extreme and i don't believe that a normal person would write it but it's definitely "fixable" with a bit of extra code.

Comment: yes quite agree, at the first I also were trying to write my function with this format but changed it before posting because it needed a little more reviewing and checking.

Comment: I wrote a version which handles this extra exception for the sake of seeing how it looks :)

Comment: that's great, but I think using a huge number of built-in "functions" within "case" statements with multiple "when"s may have negative effect on performance when executing query of huge data, however I confess this is good solution also, congrats and regards.

Comment: When trying to pull off something like this its hard to write efficient queries even in this state the code doesn't handle the "25BMainStreet" or "Main25BStreet" and probably many many more cases but it just looks irresistibly fun not to give it a try :)).

Comment: Thank you all very much, this has been extremely helpful .. it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: So what was your solution at the end ? :p